# Dotnet Installing Custom Templates Issue

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core

I have created a project Template for MS Orleans Grain (.NET Standard 2.0 project)
To install using this command:

```
dotnet new -i OrleansGrain.NetCore.ProjectTemplate::*
```

The package is hosted on Nuget.org, with .NET Console App I managed to make it work, but this package is .NET Standard 2.0 Class Library and when I try to install i got the following error message:

> C:\Users\thiag.templateengine\dotnetcli\v2.1.403\scratch\restore.csproj
>   : error NU1202: Package OrleansGrain.NetCore.ProjectTemplate 1.0.2 is
>   not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package
>   OrleansGrain.NetCore.ProjectTemplate 1.0.2 supports: netstandard2.0
>   (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)   Generating MSBuild file
>   C:\Users\thiag.templateengine\dotnetcli\v2.1.403\scratch\obj\restore.csproj.nuget.g.props.
>   Generating MSBuild file
>   C:\Users\thiag.templateengine\dotnetcli\v2.1.403\scratch\obj\restore.csproj.nuget.g.targets.
>   Restore failed in 1.73 sec for
>   C:\Users\thiag.templateengine\dotnetcli\v2.1.403\scratch\restore.csproj.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue, when creating a Nuget Package for Project Template we should use Nuget command line.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/cli-ref-pack

Need to create nuspec file and use:

```
nuget pack file.nuspec
```

Then the nupkg is generated correctly, instead from solution on Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there IS a way of making this work with the SDK style projects.

Via https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/msbuild-targets#suppress-dependencies, there's a `SuppressDependenciesWhenPacking` property when added and set to `true` in the .csproj file will skip adding the `<dependencies>` node to the generated .nuspec file.

Here's an example of a PropertyGroup that will generate a proper dotnet template package.

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
    <Description>SDK Style Test Template</Description>
    <PackageType>Template</PackageType>
    <PackageId>SDKStyle.DotNetTemplate.Test</PackageId>
    <Product>SDKStyle.DotNetTemplate.Test</Product>
    <Version>1.0</Version>
    <Authors>SDKStyle.DotNetTemplate.Test</Authors>
    <Company>SDKStyle.DotNetTemplate.Test</Company>
    <SuppressDependenciesWhenPacking>true</SuppressDependenciesWhenPacking>
  </PropertyGroup>
```